# Fix dead USB ports/Bluetooth without shutting down PC

Tags: linux, usb, linux-mint, bluetooth, hardware-failure

**Computer**
Linux Mint, 24/7 operation

**Problem**

- Manifests after a couple of days of operation.
- Lower USB ports stop transferring data. Power still works, but weakly.
  USB on the motherboard is affected, too.
- Bluetooth hardware not recognized as existing.

**Poor fix**
Shutdown computer. Leave shut off for a few hours at least before turning it on again.

**Questions**

- Root cause?
- Fix without shutting down?
- Preventative measure?

Comment: Find hardware diagnostics that will run from a bootable USB key and test the hardware.

Comment: The root cause is hard to pinpoint but considering it happens only after days of continuous work and seems to resolve itself after powering it off for a few hours, overheating is very likely.

Answer (score 1):

Although I have never before heard of a USB controller (chip on the motherboard) overheating, the symptoms you describe definitely sounds like that is what is happening.

Hopefully, you can identify which chip is the USB controller.  It might require googling chip manufacturer and model numbers to identify it.  You could then try adding some thermal paste and a heat sink to it.  You can buy these from eBay, Amazon, or an electronic parts supplier.  If the chip itself isnt damaged, this *may* resolve the issue.

If the computer is under warranty, you might want to contact the manufacturer.  It could be a hardware issue and they would replace the motherboard.

Alternatively, you can buy a USB controller addon card and stop using the faulty one.  But you may lose the ability to use ports built into the PC, depending on the design of their connector.